# Is an Americano the same as drip coffee?

Tags: espresso, drip-brew

I'm curious about the difference between an Americano (espresso + water) and drip coffee (grounds + water).

Does an Americano taste the same as black drip coffee? Whats the difference in caffeine levels? Process?

Answer (score 7):

#### Differences

- **Crema**: an espresso has [crema](https://coffee.fandom.com/wiki/Crema) whereas drip brew coffee doesn't. The reason for this is that an espresso is pulled under pressure.
- **Paper filtered**: drip brew tends to be filtered by paper of cloth, filtering out oily components. From [Comparison of nine common coffee extraction methods: instrumental and sensory analysis](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00217-013-1917-x) (where the French press is similar to espresso in that it isn't paper filtered):

  > The most efficient extraction of fatty acids was performed with French Press extraction. Brewing with a paper filter resulted in coffee with the lowest fatty acid content, which is consistent with the findings of Peters.

  Of course, this doesn't apply to all drip brews, metal filters don't filter out oily components.

#### (Possible) similarities

- **Strength**: since an Americano is a diluted  espresso, you can make it the same strength as a drip brew coffee by adding an appropriate amount of water. The opposite isn't true, you cannot make a drip coffee that has espresso-strength.
- **Ingredients**: both are made using roasted coffee and water only.

Answer (score 2):

Espresso is made from a much finer grind than drip coffee, exposed to much higher pressure and heat, diluted with hot water.

Supposedly, American GI's were put off by the stronger coffee while in Europe, hence the name.

If you're looking for a with and way way too make Americano-like coffee at home, try an Aeropress ($20.00) and don't dilute the produced coffee.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.  Drip coffee is made by running the water through the grounds in a paper or mesh filter.  This is a gravity-based brewing method used in most standard coffee makers and pour overs.  An Americano is an espresso-based drip-like beverage.  It's made by pulling espresso shots and adding them to hot (or cold if you're into that kind of thing) water.  The flavors will be different as well. For example, drip coffee will tend to have a stronger flavor, while an Americano will usually be a bit smoother depending on how strong you make it.

Answer (score -1):

I use a French press a home, I used to have a domestic machine that would be able to make Americarno’s, I my opinion an Americarno made by a proper machine is a stronger better tasting coffee

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Note that a French press is not a drip brew.